# What happened to Agent Joseph Keenan at the end of Red State?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-state

In the movie [Red State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_State_%282011_film%29), [Kevin Smith says he wanted to shoot the Apocalypse](https://youtu.be/DtXEtwAVgEc) at the end but it would cost too much. That got me to wondering:

Was Agent Keenan (John Goodman) actually dead at the end, when he's sitting in the room with the 2 agents, being judged? There's no chronological transition from the moment when the Preacher is in his face; instead it's a sudden cut to Agent Keenan coming out of a reverie. He finds he's in a different location, being judged. His fate is being decided. The agents behind the tables, which are raised up above Agent Keenan, gently lure the truth out of him. Then they tell him he's being "relocated" (if you know what I mean).

And before that, back at the church, the hours-long, non-stop gun fight would have been heard by the nearby eco-friendly potheads. I doubt the potheads would think it was a good time to play their "Judgment Day" prank by blasting trumpet notes through an old speaker.